# Analytic function. Bounding number of zeros with the number of critical points

Tags: real-analysis, analyticity

Let $f$ be a real analytic function on $|x|< R$.

Let $N(R,f)$ be the number of zeros of $f$ in the region of analyticity.
Can  we show taht 
\begin{align}
N(R,f) \le N(R,f^\prime)+2
\end{align}
wher $f^\prime$ is a derivative of $f$.

Because $f$ is analytic we know that the number of zeros $N(R,f)$ and the number of critical points $N(R,f)$ is finite (this follows from Liouville's theorem).

How to cleanly argue the above bound?  Also, a reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 
$$
 x_1 < x_2 < \ldots < x_n
$$
are the zeros of $f$ in $|x| < R$, with multiplicities $k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_n$, then $f'$ has zeros of multiplicity $k_j-1$ at $x_j$, and
also at least one zero in each interval $(x_j, x_{j+1})$, because of
Rolle's theorem. This gives
$$
 N(R, f') \ge (k_1 - 1) + \ldots (k_n-1) + (n-1) 
= (k_1 + \ldots + k_n) - 1 = N(R, f) -1 \, ,
$$
i.e. $N(R, f) \le N(R, f') + 1$.